# Index of a subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $H$ be a subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ and defined as
$$
H = \left\{
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d 
\end{bmatrix}\mid
a\equiv 1 \bmod 3,\ b\equiv 0 \bmod 3,\ c\equiv 0 \bmod 3,\ d\equiv 1 \bmod 3 \right\}.
$$

Find the index of $H$ in $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$.

Answer (score 2):

$H$ is the kernel of the epimorphism
$$ GL_2(\Bbb Z)\to GL_2(\Bbb F_3).$$
We conclude that $$[GL_2(\Bbb Z):H]=|GL_2(\Bbb F_3)|.$$ We compute the latter by observing that the first row is any non-zero vector $\in\Bbb F_3^2$, and then the second row is any vector not on the line given by the first, i.e.,
$$ |GL_2(\Bbb F_3)|=(3^2-1)\cdot(3^2-3)=48.$$